# create table from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
                         6 Months                                     1 Year
                  LDL<100   LDL<70  LDL>50% Reduction         LDL<100   LDL<70  LDL>50% Reduction
Education-only      
Medication Management                       
 ASCVD  
 DM 
 LDL>190    
 Primary Prevention
```

How can I create a table like this in pandas, I have a dataset that has Education only and a Medication Management column.

Kindly share code, I tried few codes no one look like this.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you post the code you've tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To create the empty table you may try this following code

```py
import pandas as pd


def create_column_index():
    """ Define the column index """
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        ("6 Months", "LDL<100"),
        ("6 Months", "LDL<70"),
        ("6 Months", "LDL>50% Reduction"),
        ("1 Year", "LDL<100"),
        ("1 Year", "LDL<70"),
        ("1 Year", "LDL>50% Reduction"),
    ])


def create_row_index():
    """ Define the row index """
    return pd.Index([
        "Education-only",
        "Medication Management",
        "ASCVD",
        "DM",
        "LDL>190",
        "Primary Prevention"
    ])

def create_empty_dataframe():
    # create the empty dataframe
    return pd.DataFrame(index=create_row_index(), columns=create_column_index())

df = create_empty_dataframe()
print(df)
```

Then you can fill the data into a specific cell using this code

```py
# Fill the data
df.loc["Education-only", ("6 Months", "LDL<100")] = 10
df.loc["Medication Management", ("1 Year", "LDL<70")] = 20
print(df)
```